# Using sum for two conditions with same attribute

Tags: mysql, sql

When I am creating a table to count the user between 18-40, I need to have two conditions about BirthYear in the expression like `sum((age>=18 and age<=40) and (Gender='M'))`, but the return for this one always equal 0, the whole query and output like below,  (MySQL 5.30)

```
 create table AgeUser
        select
                Id as 'Id',
                sum((age<18) and (Gender='M')) as 'MaleUsersUnder18',
                sum((age>=18 and age<=40) and (Gender='M')) as 'MaleUsers18To40',
                sum((age>40) and (Gender='M')) as 'MaleUsersOver40',
                sum((age<18) and (Gender='F')) as 'FemaleUsersUnder18',
                sum((age>=18 and age<=40) and (Gender='F')) as 'FemaleUsers18To40',
                sum((age>40) and (Gender='F')) as 'FemaleUsersOver40'
                from User group by Id;


id  MUUnder18  MU18To40  MUOver40  FUUnder18  FU18To40  FUOver40
72      2137     0         1316     645         0         123
79      2613     0         1616     1064        0         676
82      592      0         363      203         0         554
```

example for User table
The Id mean the Service Station ID

```
Id  userid  Name  age   gender     UserType
72    12     L     18     M        customer
```

How do I fix the query?

Comment: What are the values in your User table - Without knowing that - it is very difficult to comment

Comment: @code_Kbd OK, I provided a sample for user

Comment: @LeeAlex in place of `SUM` I believe you should use `COUNT` and you can use BETWEEN when you compare age (18,40)

Comment: @code_kbd result also is 0

Comment: Your code is fine.  You have no rows that match that condition.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I don't understand lol

Comment: @LeeAlex . . . Apparently, you have no users between 18 and 40.  The `age` column probably does not mean what you think it means ("age" is generally a very dangerous column in a table because it changes literally every day).

Comment: @GordonLinoff but I saw the user table has someone between 18 to 40

Comment: @LeeAlex . . . Then their gender is neither `'M'` nor `'F'`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, the gender not match, this is good

Answer (score 1):

Best sum something

```
sum(case when age<18 and Gender='M' then 1 else 0 end) as 'MaleUsersUnder18',
```

etc..

Comment: The OP's syntax is fine for MySQL.

Comment: result still is 0